# Symfony upgrade from 2.0 to current version

Tags: json, symfony, upgrade, composer-php

I got a site using Symfony 2.0 and want to upgrade it to last version of Symfony (2.4 from what I see on github).

I have already done one step: upgrade to 2.1. I fixed all issues and now I am ready to upgrade to 2.2 (I am not sure I could go to the current version directly). From my understanding, to do so, I need to retrieve the composer.json on github and add my own dependencies (only one). Is that right?

I tried to do it and it failed. Furthermore Symfony folder under vendor is empty after this attempt. I checked the composer.json for 2.2 and I do not see any symfony specified in it. Did I miss something?

Any help would be more than welcome :o)

Answer (score 1):

ok the problem was only due to the fact that I was getting the composer.json from the wrong github repository. Be sure to use the one from the symfony-standard repository.

Answer (score 0):

You can update from `Symfony 2.0` to `Symfony 2.4` directly. And yes, for it you need original [composer.json](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.4/composer.json) file of Symfony 2.4 in `symfony/symfony-standard` repository and add to it your own dependencies if you have

Comment: 2.0 does not have composer. That's why I first upgraded to 2.1. If I use the composer.json from github (I guess this is what you mean by original composer.json), I got errors and symfony is removed too. Any idea?

Comment: Yes, I mean this [composer.json](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.4/composer.json), Show error message, please

Comment: Oh I have maybe found the problem. I was not using the correct composer.json. I got the one from the github repository symfony/symfony, and not the one from symfony/symfony-standard. This one looks better. Let's try :)

Comment: Yes, you need to use `symfony/symfony-standard`, becouse `symfony/symfony` is a core of framework :)